# How can I reset my password in recovery mode

Tags: macos, password, administrator

I am unable to use “resetpassword” for this and cannot sign into any of my accounts until I reset my password. I cannot leave recovery mode until I have the password so I cannot run a “sudo” command.

I am running MacOS Big Sur 11.6.1 and am trying to reinstall macOS with my password because of another issue with my computer.

I was just wondering if anyone knows a password reset command that will work on my administrator account so I can reinstall macOS?

Comment: To be clear, does the Mac boot to any account? If so, you might be able to check for MDM or other details that would help other than sending you to Apple support to try each reset option sequentially. There are quite a lot, and you do want to do them in order. Reset password is way down the list and often not needed.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the Apple page on where you can reset your password in Recovery mode: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202860, and here is the other page (linked on the first page) to try if you didn't have success with the first page: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT212190. Upon reading those 2 pages, it feels like if you don't have an Apple ID, it seems almost impossible to reset your password, so I hope you have access to an Apple ID.

If you've also tried all the incredible recovery options listed in this [CNET link](https://www.cnet.com/tech/computing/dont-panic-if-you-forgot-your-mac-password-you-can-still-get-back-in/), and you're still locked out, then I don't know. I'm guessing your school has an administrator account with the Macbook as well.

Comment: Thank you it fixed it, I was originally just trying dscl commands but this worked thanks!